# How to return qr code as image png to ajax in CI 4

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter, qr-code, codeigniter-4

Currently i'm using class from https://github.com/endroid/qr-code and i have return $qrCode->writeString() from controller as json_encode to AJAX. But the qr code result is not image. Is it possible to make qr code result as image(png) without save the image ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it with below code :

Controller :

```
$qrCode->setWriterByExtension('png'); //change it to png
```

return value to AJAX with `$qrCode->writeDataUri()` not `$qrCode->writeString()`

and parse the value into img src attr